# Can you remove a capacitor and add wires to both solder pads?

Tags: capacitor, soldering

I have a project I'm working on and I'm just going to ask a conceptual question just to make sure this is possible before I do it.

There is a signal that goes through a capacitor before going into a pin on an IC. I want to remove this capacitor and wire two separate wires to the capacitor's solder pads: one coming from the chip side and one on the other side.

I'm going to solder a wire on the input side pad to an on-on switch that has another signal on the top side of the switch.

The chip side solder pad will be wired to the output of the switch. The output will have the same capacitor removed previously added to it on the switch before going to the pin on the chip.

Would this work? I'm not sure because I've never seen someone do this specific thing before and I don't want to remove the capacitor for no reason.

Comment: Please list what the signals that go through the capacitor are and the frequency.

Comment: What do you mean "goes through a capacitor"? Is the cap in series with the IC or sitting towards ground? Because the former would be rare unless we are talking specific analog parts. You need to know the purpose of the cap in that case, before messing around with it. Perhaps you could draw a simple schematic including the IC partnumber and datasheet?

Comment: What is "an on-on switch"?

Comment: @Lundin the former would actually be quite common in the kinds of circuits that would be messed up by adding some wires and an on/off switch!

Comment: @user253751 It's perfectly unclear at least to me what the OP is dealing with and what they are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

> Would this work?

It will if the wires and switch have parasitics that don't matter to the IC.
If the capacitor is on the order of lower than 100nF I think you might have a problem, because most blue wires will have nH of inductance and you'll be adding in some capacitance with the wires and the switch that could change the total capacitance.

It also depends on frequencies, anything above ~50MHz will be difficult to get through wires because of inductance, below that you might be ok.

Answer (score 3):

I might work, but it depends on what kind of signal is going through the capacitor and how stable the circuit will be with wires added.

Wires will add inductance and possibly pick up stray signals. If it's a high frequency analog, fast switching digital, or low level signal this could be a problem. The longer the wires the more likely it is to cause issues.

The other thing you have to be careful of is lifting the solder pads. They're not meant to have wires attached to them, and after repeated soldering/unsoldering/soldering the glue that holds them to the board will be weakened. The strain of wires pulling on them can cause them to pull off the board and that can be difficult to repair.